# « Give a bad name to / give someone or something a bad name » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, usage, expressions-idiomatiques, constructions

En langue anglaise on a l'idiome « [give a bad name to](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/give-a-bad-name-to) » (aussi « give someone or something a bad name ») dans le sens de « [spoil](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/spoil/614061) the reputation of » (*Dictionary.com*), gâcher, nuire à... ; on donne l'exemple « Late deliveries are giving the company a bad name » : les retards dans la livraison... Chez [*Larousse*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/name/596850#596851) en ligne on donne pour « to have a bad name » la traduction « avoir (une) mauvaise réputation » : ce peut être littéralement la réputation... mais avec le [chien](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/dog/576395?q=bad%20name#637389) c'est l'accuser de la rage pour le noyer, proverbial.

- Est-ce à la *réputation*, à l'*image* ou à l'*opinion* à laquelle on
  réfère le plus usuellement comme étant la chose qu'on gâche ou selon
  quels facteurs (éléments contextuels; est-ce uniquement selon que
  c'est animé/inanimé) le détermine-t-on et trouve-t-on souhaitable ou
  non de choisir le verbe de l'idiome (*to give*, donner, avec
  *mauvaise*, par exemple) ou le verbe du sens (*to spoil*, gâcher etc.) et au final sur quelle combinaison arrête-t-on son choix et
  surtout, pourquoi ?

---

In English you have this idiom "[give a bad name to](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/give-a-bad-name-to)" (also "give someone or something a bad name") as in "[spoil](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/spoil/614061) the reputation of" (*Dictionary.com*) which is like *gâcher, nuire à...*; and you have this example from the dictionary entry "Late deliveries are giving the company a bad name": *les retards dans la livraison...* [*Larousse*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/name/596850#596851) online translates "to have a bad name" with "*avoir (une) mauvaise réputation*" : so it can be about *reputation* per se... yet with the [dog](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/dog/576395?q=bad%20name#637389) and hanging, that would yield an indictment and drowning, as in the proverbial *qui veut noyer son chien l'accuse de la rage* [rabies].

- So usually does one refer to the *réputation*, the *image* or the
  *opinion* as the thing being spoiled by whatever here or what comes into play (context elements; is it only about whether this is
  animate/inanimate) in selecting one or the other, and is it
  preferable to select the verb from the original idiom (to give,
  *donner*, with *mauvaise* for instance) or the verb from the meaning (to spoil, *gâcher* etc.), and what does one settle for in the end in
  terms of construction, and most importantly, why?

---

> Ça donne une mauvaise image/opinion/réputation de/à telle
>   chose/personne.
>  Ça nuit à l'image/la réputation/à l'opinion qu'on
>   se fait de telle chose/personne.
>  Ça teinte l'expérience ?
>   ...

Comment: On peut aussi éluder: _Les retards de livraison nuisent à l'entreprise_.

Answer (score 3):

Je pense que *Donner une mauvaise image* et *Donner une mauvaise réputation* seraient les expressions que j'utiliserais le plus intuitivement en français (autant oral qu'écrit). On pourrait aussi utiliser les verbes *[ternir](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/ternir/77419)* ou *[salir](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/salir/70697)* :

> La qualité du service après-vente ternit vraiment l'image de cette
>   société.