# « He that hath a ill name is half hanged » ?

Tags: anglais, comparaison-de-langues, proverbes, registre

On [sait](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/26454/3177) qu'en langue anglaise on a l'emploi de *bad name* (parfois aussi *ill name*), possiblement en référence à la [réputation](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/name/596850#596851), qui remonte à 1400 et on trouve le proverbe suivant dès 1576 :

> **He that [hath](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/hath) a ill name is half [hanged](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hang#Usage_notes).** 
> [mot à mot : *celui qui a un nom malade* (*ill name* pour *bad name*, mauvaise réputation) *est a moitié pendu*.]
>
> [ [The American Heritage Dictionary of Idioms](https://books.google.ca/books?id=9QuEiIMaBt0C&lpg=PA173&ots=fHM1sHvQ27&dq=%22He%20that%20hath%20a%20ill%20name%20is%20half%20hanged%22&hl=fr&pg=PA173#v=onepage&q=%22He%20that%20hath%20a%20ill%20name%20is%20half%20hanged%22&f=false), deuxième édition,
>   C. Ammer, Houghton Mifflin Harcourt, 2013, à l'entrée « give a bad name to », mes commentaires entre crochets ]

- A-t-on un proverbe ou une phrase célèbre de sens similaire avec la
  [*réputation*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/r%C3%A9putation) ou une sémantique apparentée et qu'y trouve-t-on
  comme conséquence : le pendu, le perdu, la mort... ?
- Incidemment sinon comment traduirait-on ce proverbe en respectant sa
  qualité stylistique (le proverbe) et son registre (possiblement archaïsant) ?

Comment: Pas une phrase célèbre, mais une chanson célèbre: [La mauvaise réputation](http://www.paroles.net/georges-brassens/paroles-la-mauvaise-reputation) de Georges Brassens.

Comment: @mouviciel Merci ! Ça finit même avec une référence à la pendaison ! C'est sans doute trop intéressant et pertinent pour ne rester qu'en commentaire. Je vous invite à verser ça en réponse.

Comment: Voilà qui est fait.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Un proverbe français proche mais pas très connu est :

> Le bruit pend l'homme.

Dictionnaire des proverbes françois, 1758:

[image]

Comment: Jamais entendu, mais on en comprend facilement le sens. Merci !

Answer (score 4):

Je ne propose ni un proverbe, ni une phrase célèbres, mais une chanson célèbre: [La mauvaise réputation](http://www.paroles.net/georges-brassens/paroles-la-mauvaise-reputation) de Georges Brassens.

> Je ne fais pourtant de tort à personne,
>   En suivant les ch’mins qui ne mèn’nt pas à Rome ;
>   Mais les brav’s gens n'aiment pas que
>   L'on suive une autre route qu'eux…

Answer (score 3):

La traduction pratiquement littérale de l'expression semble également s'utiliser en français ([1](http://citation-celebre.leparisien.fr/citations/64599), [2](http://evene.lefigaro.fr/citation/mauvaise-reputation-moitie-pendu-23642.php)) :

> Celui qui a mauvaise réputation est à moitié pendu.

Il s'agit d'une citation de [John Heywood](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Heywood), un écrivain anglais, qui a été traduite en français.

---

Ceci dit, j'aime bien le proverbe proposé par [*jlliagre*](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/26456/13109), qui est plus court, plus élégant.

Comment: Merci, selon vous ne serait-il pas plus naturel de retrouver _déjà_ dans la phrase ? Pensez-vous que cette traduction porte la marque du proverbial, que ce soit au niveau du lexique ou de la syntaxe ?

Comment: Effectivement, *Celui qui a mauvaise réputation est déjà à moitié pendu* paraît très bien aussi. La traduction littérale de l'expression reste celle que j'ai trouvé est celle que j'ai postée en réponse. Il s'agit avec évidence d'un proverbe, mais je suppose qu'on peut se permettre quelques libertés ... :-)